# possible ways to store JSON in dynamodb

Tags: java, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am working on an implementation where my system will be integrated with an external application. This external application generates long and different json for every request.

I want to store this json in dynamodb, what would be the best approach to do that? Currently, I have created a POJO class with below property. In this definition property, I set the API response json as string.

```
@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "definition")
private String definition;
```

Then create object of POJO, and save it to dynamodb using `this.dynamoDBMapper.save(obj);`

Questions:

1 - Is this a good approach to store JSON in dynamodb as string?

2 - What if I want to search by any property of this json in dynamodb?

3 - Is there a better way to store this json so it can be searchable also?

Also, this json is always different so I can't map it to POJO class, that's why I am trying to store it as a string.

Below is my sample POJO object that I am storing in dynamo db.

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "job")
public class Job {

@DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "inbound_job")
private Long inboundId;

@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "outbound_job")
private Long outboundId;

@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "definition")
private String definition;
}
```

Below is respective json stored in dynamodb.

```
{
    "inbound_job": {
        "N": "3138788"
    },
    "outbound_id": {
        "N": "909092"
    },
    "jobDefinition": {
        "S": "{\r\n\t\"_id\": \"5ae1d9848376948a370d6962\",\r\n\t\"index\": 4,\r\n\t\"guid\": \"32bb8da0-a84a-4b3c-8775-c20216fa04b7\",\r\n\t\"isActive\": true,\r\n\t\"balance\": \"$2,683.96\",\r\n\t\"picture\": \"http:\/\/placehold.it\/32x32\",\r\n\t\"age\": 38,\r\n\t\"eyeColor\": \"brown\",\r\n\t\"name\": \"Swanson Hughes\",\r\n\t\"gender\": \"male\",\r\n\t\"company\": \"BIOSPAN\",\r\n\t\"email\": \"swansonhughes@biospan.com\",\r\n\t\"phone\": \"+1 (999) 559-2315\",\r\n\t\"address\": \"851 Lyme Avenue, Shepardsville, American Samoa, 8015\",\r\n\t\"about\": \"Sit officia culpa in est Lorem. Officia occaecat nostrud Lorem officia non sint enim excepteur. Laboris dolore consectetur velit occaecat ullamco non nisi.\\r\\n\",\r\n\t\"registered\": \"2015-12-12T11:22:53 +08:00\",\r\n\t\"latitude\": 47.732205,\r\n\t\"longitude\": -164.823761,\r\n\t\"tags\": [\r\n\t\t\"velit\",\r\n\t\t\"anim\",\r\n\t\t\"id\",\r\n\t\t\"tempor\",\r\n\t\t\"et\",\r\n\t\t\"eu\",\r\n\t\t\"amet\"\r\n\t],\r\n\t\"friends\": [{\r\n\t\t\t\"id\": 0,\r\n\t\t\t\"name\": \"Kaye Fields\"\r\n\t\t},\r\n\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\"id\": 1,\r\n\t\t\t\"name\": \"Knapp Reed\"\r\n\t\t},\r\n\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\"id\": 2,\r\n\t\t\t\"name\": \"Hodge Morse\"\r\n\t\t}\r\n\t],\r\n\t\"greeting\": \"Hello, Swanson Hughes! You have 3 unread messages.\",\r\n\t\"favoriteFruit\": \"strawberry\"\r\n}"
    }
}
```

I also want to search by any json property of "definition" attribute.

Let me know your thoughts.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is a good way to store your arbitrary json data.

You can then use [document path](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.Attributes.html) in your queries and scans to find and retrieve parts of the responses. You don't need to do anything special when you save the json (other than make sure the json is properly escaped).

Its worth noting that you can only index top level DynamoDB item attributes. This means any 'search' you do on your response content will be a scan, which will evaluate every response in the table.

If there are any (reliable/consistent) attributes you want to index, you will need to extract them from the json and make them an attribute on the POJO.

Comment: Hi, i have updated my original question with pojo & dynamodb json. "jobDefinition" attribute has json stored in string. so can i use document path to search with in any property of "jobDefinition" attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using dynamoDBMapper, you can use Table.putItem.
Refer [DynamoDB Java docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Java.02.html) for updating any free json into dynamodb.

Highlights from the above link (tweaked for your use-case):

```
    AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
        .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("http://localhost:8000", "us-west-2"))
        .build();
    DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(client);
    Table table = dynamoDB.getTable("YourTableName");
    try {
      table.putItem(new Item().withPrimaryKey("hashKeyName", hashKeyValue).withJSON("definition", definition);
      System.out.println("PutItem succeeded: " );
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println(e.getMessage());
      break;
    }
```

Comment: yes, i tried that as well. Advantage of using dynamoDBMapper is i can configure prefix and use objects directly to save into dynamo db. With AmazonDynamoDB client, i will have to provide table name(which is diff for each env) and exact property names.

Comment: @user3552454 Do you have nesting in your JSON?

Comment: You could create an attribute of type hashMap<String, String>

Comment: i have modified my original question with pojo and sample json stored in dynamodb. Definition attribute is API response of some app, which changes always. so i am storing it in dynamodb. but i also want to have ability to search in that json.

Comment: @user3552454 can u try to change definition to HashMap<String, String>, if this doesn't work -  try HashMap<String, Object> - Not sure if this will work tho.

Comment: tried, with HaspMap<string, string> only diff i see is now my json is stored as value to key. Thanks.

Comment: @user3552454 The incoming string must be passed to definition..ideally the json must be converted to hashMap. What is the key you are observing? Can u post code, how u saved it as json?